# AttributeError: 'test' object has no attribute 'driver'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest

*Hi I am new to python and Selenium I have created a framework using Python and Selenium.When I am trying to run a test suite in pytest I am facing an error -the object has no attribute 'driver'*

Config_test.py
[image: Config_test.py]

Base_class.py

[image: Base_Class.py]

Test_D2C.py
[image: Test_D2C for running the test module]

[image]

Error message I am getting
[image: Facing error message : obj has no attribute driver]

Comment: Please add your code as text instead of screenshots.